# Open 2 separate chromium tabs in full screen on startup, then auto scroll on one of them

Tags: javascript, linux, shell, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on an information display about the current situation that is going on in the world right now.

My task is to modify a Raspberry Pi, running Pi OS, to:

- Open 2 separate browser windows on boot in full screen next to each other.
- Edit one of them so that the website automatically scrolls to display all the information on the site.

I know how to open a single browser window on boot in fullscreen, but not two next to each other.
And I know how to edit the page's *JavaScript* so it automatically scrolls, but not how to edit it from the *Linux* command line.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT 1:

I am ignoring the autoscroll-part and simply want to have 2 browser-windows in split screen next to each other. To achieve that, i tried to:

- find a way to set the position with the window manager, but the window manager used for Raspberry Pi OS does not offer that.
- set the window size and position with `--window-size` and `--window-position`, but it didn't work. Always opens with max resolution.
- use Firefox, but the problem was the same there as well.

I am running out of options and really need help.

Comment: Which browser is used in your case?

Comment: I am using Chromium. I am currently looking into different browsers that may work better for that task.